# Does which view i use matter when trying to hide keyboard?

Tags: android

Let's say i have a few views in the same layout, and i call:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(someView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

does the `someView` matter?

I tried a simple example of hiding the keyboard, but i didn't notice any difference in terms of hiding the keyboard. Where do the subtle differences come in?

Answer (score 1):

Seems it doesn't matter, actually, until this view is from the same window.
As documentation said [View.getWindowToken()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWindowToken%28%29):

> Retrieve a unique token identifying the window this view is attached
>   to.

All activity views are attached to the same window. So, you'll get the same token from every view.

However, if You have keyboard visible and show some dialog. Say this dialog will have some custom view:

**dialog_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tryHideKeyboard"
        android:text="Try hide keyboard"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**TestDialogFragment.java**

```
public class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

        view.findViewById(R.id.tryHideKeyboard).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });

        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Test dialog")
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                        // nothing to do
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Then pressing `Try hide keyboard` button in the dialog (opened in the activity with for example EditText on main layout and keyboard visible), keyboard behind won't be closed, because dialogs have own window.

So, I would say that no, it doesn't matter until you try to close keyboard from view which attached to another window (e.g. from popup dialog).